# How can i round a UIView

Tags: swift, uiview

Please could you help me, i would like to round a UIView in Swift like in the photogram app.

[Photogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybmz4.png)

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it, but I guess you could use a normal UIView and put your other views inside this view (in Photogram case you use MKMapView and 3 UILabels (title, subtitle, body)) and use layer.cornerRadius with huge corner radius (maybe 50 should work).

If you want to do it in code you should create an outlet from your UIView from storyboard to the view controller (Ctrl + drag) and use this code:

```
myUIView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
myUIView.layer.maskToBounds = true
```

You can put this code in viewDidLoad().

If you want a solution in storyboard only you select your view and add this code from the below image (I've used it for UIButton, but it should be the same):

[image]